# The application license check that is running on a virtual machine vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere, license-key, vmware-sdk

I'm sorry for my bad english.

There is a application with license tied to the hardware. One computer - one license.
Typically, a license check is as follows:
[image: normal application license checking]

1. The application scans hardware.
2. The application collects information about the hardware and prepares a request for the license availability.
3. The application sends a request to check the availability of the license.
4. The license server receives the request and returns a response. The application receives a response from the license server and activates full functionality.

However, if the application is on the virtual machine - gathering information about the hardware fails.
[image: virtual machine application license checking 1]

I could not get information about the server hardware, as default methods do not permit do it.

Appeal to the hypervisor methods allows you to collect some statistics, but it is not enough to generate a request for the presence of licenses.
[image: virtual machine application license checking 2]

---

Thus there are 2 questions:

- How within the virtual machine, I can get information about the
  server hardware?
- How can I implement verification of the license tied to hardware, if
  the program is running on a virtual machine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guest OS and the hypervisor can communicate with each other through the VMware vSockets.